# Convert Jaspersoft xml file in to flutter code

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xml-parsing, jasper-reports

So my client wants that user creates a form or report in Jaspersoft studio and get an XML file of that form and flutter front end pick that file and convert that XML file code into flutter code and after converting that code in a flutter that code run and show the form. I am confused about whether that thing is possible and if it's possible how I can achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

XML code generated by Jaspersoft studio. That was the chunk of that generated code by Jaspersoft studio.

```
<page>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="6321f5e3-86eb-444f-acc1-8daaaa0d6c60" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="92" backcolor="#006699" origin="0" srcId="1" printId="1"/>
            <text textHeight="42.765625" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-7.470703">
                <reportElement uuid="9e48917a-7b59-4ffd-baad-725f45563194" x="20" y="20" width="234" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" origin="0" srcId="2" printId="1"/>
                <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Order]]></textContent>
            </text>
            <text textAlignment="Right" textHeight="17.609375" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-3.0761719">
                <reportElement uuid="0a399baa-bad3-4b1a-9fe3-bb1c563e6a27" x="395" y="43" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" origin="0" srcId="3" printId="1"/>
                <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                <textContent><![CDATA[Testing the order]]></textContent>
            </text>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="2278b046-0e96-4025-83fa-9c35bac203a6" x="20" y="105" width="540" height="690" origin="4" srcId="7" printId="2">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.tableUUID" value="2278b046-0e96-4025-83fa-9c35bac203a6"/>
            </reportElement>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="f44cdc1c-8e5a-496d-beda-493ab750a720" style="Table_TH" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" origin="7" srcId="16" printId="1">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="jrcel cel_ORDERDATE_1325012930_0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text textHeight="23.898438" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-4.1748047">
                    <reportElement uuid="fd48262d-174e-4d8e-8b0e-da62eb20a1c8" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" origin="7" srcId="17" printId="1"/>
                    <font size="19" isBold="true"/>
                    <textContent><![CDATA[Header]]></textContent>
                </text>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="48e54e2c-102d-4443-879b-e27373f25504" style="Table_TH" x="90" y="0" width="90" height="30" origin="7" srcId="18" printId="1">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="jrcel cel_SHIPPEDDATE_1156636890_0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text textHeight="23.898438" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-4.1748047">
                    <reportElement uuid="6abca231-4f43-4538-9784-021a62e23f88" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" origin="7" srcId="19" printId="1"/>
                    <font size="19" isBold="true"/>
                    <textContent><![CDATA[Header]]></textContent>
                </text>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="ca332291-0f78-4f82-b803-a0b25d04591a" style="Table_TH" x="180" y="0" width="90" height="30" origin="7" srcId="20" printId="1">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="jrcel cel_SHIPNAME_2110597027_0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text textHeight="23.898438" lineSpacingFactor="1.2578125" leadingOffset="-4.1748047">
                    <reportElement uuid="6ba7657f-9e87-42b3-9208-e6634155e915" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" origin="7" srcId="21" printId="1"/>
                    <font size="19" isBold="true"/>
                    <textContent><![CDATA[Header]]></textContent>
                </text>
            </frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, keep some widgets for each possible entry in the XML form, then when you receive the XML form, just run it through a parsing function you'd create. This parsing function will take in the XML and give out a list of widgets required. Once you have the list of widgets, you can use a list view builder to build them on a screen.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any examples related to that it's really helpful?

Comment: I don't have an example as such. Although it should be pretty similar to making cardsfrom an API that returns posts. The cards would be the form fields and the posts would be your XML elements.